# getting ' JSON EXCEPTION: no value for ' error?

Tags: java, android, json, getjson

i'm trying to parse a json array "itemList":

```
 {
    "itemsCount": "1309",
    "itemList": [
        { name: "xxx",
          id: "01"
        },
        { name: "yyy",
          id: "02"
        }
      ]
    }
```

but i got " json exception:no value for "
when i use the following code.

```
 String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ALBUMS, "GET", params);
Log.d("Albums JSON: ", "> " + json);                    
try {   
     jsonObject = new JSONObject().getJSONObject("itemList");
     albums = jsonObject.getJSONArray("itemList"); 
         if (albums != null) {

    for (int i = 0; i < albums.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = albums.getJSONObject(i);

    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);


    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);


    albumsList.add(map);
                }
            }else{
                Log.d("Albums: ", "null");
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

in the log i'm able to see the json values. i'm getting error in following lines.

```
jsonObject = new JSONObject().getJSONObject("itemList");
 albums = jsonObject.getJSONArray("itemList");
```

i'm new to this .help me solve it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the type of your 'album' obj ?

Comment: itemList is jsonarray , and you are taking it as json object, so you are getting the error, directly parse it as json array.

Comment: Where do you set the json String as content for your JSONObject? And how can you first get an objcet "itemList" and then an array out of this? Try, init yout jsonObject with the json string new JSONObject(json) and then get the array out of this josnObject.getJSONArray("itemList")

Comment: itemList is jsonarray , and you are trying to fetch as json object, so you are getting the error in your line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the json string for creating a jsong object.

```
jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
 albums = jsonObject.getJSONArray("itemList");
```

Comment: i tried it. but getting "json exception: value [{ itemList json values }]"

Comment: got it. this solved my problem                                                " jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
       albums = jsonObject.getJSONArray("itemList"); "

Answer (score 0):

If this task if **not a educational/academic** one I would recommend you to use a **JSON Mapper**.
For example **Jackson** or **GSON**. "Manually" parsing JSON like this is just a waste of time and code and makes it much more error prone.

http://jackson.codehaus.org/

Doing the same things with a mapper would be two lines of code, literally.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
 jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
```